# How to find Array type and its dimensions for a multidimensional Array for an Object reference

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a Object reference which may or may not be a array.It can be a multidimensional array.I want to find the component type and length of the array dimensions.

What I have tried so far is get the runtime class type of the Object from `object.getClass()` and then count the number of `'['`.But again I would not know the dimensions of the array.
I want to know if there can be cleaner way.

PS:- I have a plain Object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Class#getComponentType()`.

```
Object ref = new int[2][3][4];
System.out.println(ref.getClass().getComponentType());
```

It will return the `Class` object for the array type, if it is an array. Otherwise it will return `null`. You can keep doing this for multidimensional arrays until it returns `null`.

You can use `Array#getLength(Object)` to find the length of each individual dimension.

```
System.out.println(Array.getLength(ref));
```

Comment: Or even better, use [`Class#isArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isArray--) in case the object reference is not an array.

Comment: And I need the dimensions also

Comment: @AbhinavKumar you can get the dimension by calling the method multiple times and using a counter...

Comment: @AbhinavKumar The `Array` class provides a nice method to get the length of an array.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes I was thinking also the same,you mean the java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(); ??

Comment: Some may confuse with java.util.Arrays

Comment: @AbhinavKumar `Array` vs `Arrays`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis for the first index,I get the array length 2 for a multidimensional array [2][3][4].How do I extract the next dimension for int[][][] array ....